# What's the difference between data source and delegate?

Tags: cocoa, delegates, protocols, datasource

I have a fundamental question related to Cocoa frameworks design patterns.

*What's the difference between delegate and data source?*

Both of them could use `@protocols` declaration, but some classes or frameworks are using `delegate`, and some others are using `datasource`.

All I can understand from `UI/NSTableView` is the `delegate` respond to UI-related events, while the `datasource` is purely related to the data. But, I don't know any data source implementations outside the UI classes of Cocoa.

**Note:**

- The delegate I mentioned in this question is not always related to UI events.
- The data source question has been answered.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The delegate and datasource patterns are largely independent, and orthogonal:

The delegate pattern is very common in Cocoa and allows a delegate (any instance implementing the informal delegate protocol prior to OS X 10.6, or the formal delegate `@protocol` in 10.6 and later) to modify the behavior of an object instance. This pattern is often used instead of subclassing: instead of subclassing a class to change its behavior, you supply a delegate that responds to the appropriate methods. Classes that use delegates send messages to their delegate at contracted events. The API between class and delegate is defined by the class and is different for each class that uses the pattern, but the API generally consists of messages asking the delegate how to handle a particular event. One advantage of the delegate pattern over subclassing is that a class may implement multiple delegate protocols, allowing its instances to act as delegate for multiple classes. Similarly, an object instance can be the delegate for multiple other objects (hence most delegate APIs pass the object as the first argument to each message in the API). The delegate pattern is not as common in other UI frameworks (though Qt does use the delegate pattern in its Model/View framework), and is *not* the same as .Net/CLR delegates which are essentially typed function pointers.

The data source pattern is often used by `NSView` sub-classes in Cocoa that have complex state data such as NSBrowser, NSTableView, NSOutlineView, etc. The data source protocol defines an API that instances of these (and other) classes may use to get the data to display in the view. Although the `NSController` and Cocoa Bindings architectures have replaced many uses of the data source pattern, it's still common and very powerful. Like the delegate pattern described above, part of its power comes from an object being able to act as the data source for multiple data-source-using instances (and possibly even instances of multiple classes that have different data source protocols). The data source pattern is used commonly in other UI frameworks, such as Qt (in the Model/View framework where the model is analogous to the data source) and WPF/Silverlight (where the data source might be more closely analogous to the view model).

Comment: Okay, a very comprehensive explanation. My understanding right now is data source don't respond to events. In the case of Cocoa classes, it only provides a way to implement what data to be displayed in a certain view.

I'm just not sure why the concept of data source is never used outside UI-related classes of Cocoa frameworks.

Comment: @Jesse Just to be clear, neither delegates nor data sources respond directly to UI events (i.e. an `NSEvent` passed to the app via the run loop). An object may ask a delegate how to respond to an event (either an `NSEvent` type event or any other message from an other object).

Data sources aren't used outside of UI classes because they're not needed; the model of MVC is its own data source.

Comment: Ok, sorry if you misunderstood. I didn't mean to say that delegate always respond to UI events. My primary concern was the "flexibility" of the term data source to be used outside UI classes. I agree and I never found any need for that outside UI classes.

Comment: The language you used is very difficult. I think only experience person can understand.

Answer (score 51):

The datasource supplies the data, the delegate supplies the behavior.

In [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), datasource is in the model layer and the delegate is in the control layer.

Actually, on second thought, the datasource is usually controller that is lower down, closer to the model. I don't think I've ever used a model object as my datasource.

Answer (score 14):

Suppose you had 3 tableviews. For dogs, cats and birds. Tapping on each cell would show a new screen with the enlarged photo of it.

To design this, you'll need to come up with 3 separate datasources for dogs, cats and birds. You basically need three arrays.

However you don't need 3 tableview delegates. Because the behavior of the tableviews are all the same. They all just take present a viewController and fill it with a UIImage. This is only true if you delegate is written in a generic way i.e. there's no dog, cat or bird specific code in the delegate.

Having that said you could abstract out the dog, cat, bird from the data source, but my answer was just a contrived example. Some custom objects are too complex to use the same structure, hence the need to have 3 datasources.

## Old answer:

Before answering the question, you must better understand the delegation design pattern:
Let me begin with a question:

**By default a TableView is like this:**

[image]

**How does a UITableView know how many cells to present? what to present in each cell?**

- By itself, it doesn't know.
- It asks another class to *inform* it about the number of cells and what cell to return ( what cellimage, celltitle, cellsubtitle,etc.) values to itself. You usually see a tableView (delegating class) inside a ViewController (delegate class)
- This concept of one class asking another is known as **delegation!**

---

Now that you know what Delegation is, to answer the actual question of the OP:

It's mostly a HUGE matter of semantic differences.
If you are only to use ( not to create your own protocol) foundation's delegates and datasources then it really doesn't matter for you. However if you intend to write custom protocols then understanding them would help you to write ( and with a higher importance read, refractor) code better.

From a developer's point of view, They both deal with the interaction between the delegat-**ing** class and delegate class.

[Data Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)

> A data source is almost identical to a delegate. The difference is in
> the relationship with the delegating object. Instead of being
> delegated control of the user interface, a data source is delegated
> control of data. The delegating object, typically a view object such
> as a table view, holds a reference to its data source and occasionally
> asks it for the data it should display. A data source, like a
> delegate, must adopt a protocol and implement at minimum the required
> methods of that protocol. Data sources are responsible for managing
> the memory of the model objects they give to the delegating view.

In Layman's terms:

DataSource deals mostly with **what** and usually does it's stuff *upon initialization*.
Delegate deals mostly with **how** and **feeds** you some parameters to give a certain behavior ie if the user clicked this... what should happen? if they swiped...what should happen?

As an example for tableView:

**DataSource**
What does it have inside of it? What kind of cell am I presenting?  `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.
What is the title of Section? `titleForHeaderInSection`
How many cells are they? `numberOfRowsInSection`
And therefore you usually *return* values. For delegates it's more common to be of type `void`.

---

**Datasource methods**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell // return a cell ie UITableViewCell
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int // return a number ie an Int
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? // return the title ie a String
```

**Delegate Methods**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

<sub>I obviously chose selectively as some datasource methods don't return and some delegate method do return</sub>

---

**Delegate**
What should I do/what 'form of behavior' should I use after finishing the display of the footer, do you want me to pop an alert?`didEndDisplayingFooterView`

Am I going to have accessoryType that gives the cell some extra features? `accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath`

Answer (score 8):

From my point of view, a `DataSource` is an object that doesn't know where the data is, and thus you should provide it. Such as telling an object how many items in a column.

A `Delegate`, which is a part that object shows to you, must be implemented by your class, because the object knows where the data is, but it does not know how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 7):

To make it short:

**Delegate** relates to the UI and User actions against the cells and table.

common methods: willSelectRow, didSelectRow, willDisplay, heightForRow, willBeginEditingAt

**Data Source** deals with the editing, population and displaying of data on 
the tableview.

common methods canEditRowAt, commit, titleForHeaderInSection, cellForRowAt, numberOfSections, sectionIndexTitles

Comment: **For more detailed info, just look over the documentation and you will clearly see their differences.

Answer (score 3):

Both are **Protocol**, now the main intension of **Protocol** is to keep an universal coding practice, or same coding practice for all(to my understanding). Suppose I am creating a tableView without a **UITableViewDataSource** & **UITableViewDelegate**, I would create the tableView such a way that you woud not. Thats where **Protocol** comes, apple created some set of rule or **protocol** and everybody have to follow that. Now **DataSource** & **Delegate** are obviously **Protocol**, seeing the name you could understand **DataSource** deals with something like **numberOfRowsInSection**, **cellForRowAtIndexPath**, **numberOfSections** of tableView where some kind of data is being taken/processed, and **Delegates** are **didSelectRow**, **willSelectRow**, **heightForRow** etc of tableView where its related with some kind of UI change/action. So its just naming convention nothing hypothetical to keep the task separate. As @kubi said earlier: The datasource supplies the data, the delegate supplies the behaviour.