# iOS Data Source Delegation, clarification needed

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

iOS lecture i downloaded from iTunesU lists 3 forms of communication from the View to a Controller

- Target-Action
- Delegation
- and separately Data Source delegation

I wonder, what is the reason to highlight Data Source delegation, as a separate form of delegation?

[image]

Comment: There is a very detailed topic on Stackoverflow about this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232147/whats-the-difference-between-data-source-and-delegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a different object for your data source than for your delegate.  That way, you can change the delegate to get different behavior without changing the data source.