# iPhone - What is data source and delegate methods in iphone?

Tags: iphone, delegates, datasource

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between data source and delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232147/whats-the-difference-between-data-source-and-delegate)

I am new to the iPhone. I am confused by what is a delegate and a data source method and what they do.  Can someone explain to me the differences?

Comment: Please search this in google and you will get plenty of results. Here is the 1 similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232147/whats-the-difference-between-data-source-and-delegate

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's [Concepts in Objective-C Programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) document:

> **Delegate** A delegate is an object that acts on behalf of, or in coordination with, another object when that object encounters an event
>   in a program. The delegating object is often a responder object—that
>   is, an object inheriting from NSResponder in AppKit or UIResponder in
>   UIKit—that is responding to a user event. The delegate is an object
>   that is delegated control of the user interface for that event, or is
>   at least asked to interpret the event in an application-specific
>   manner.
>
> To better appreciate the value of delegation, it helps to consider an
>   off-the-shelf Cocoa object such as a text field (an instance of
>   NSTextField or UITextField) or a table view (an instance of
>   NSTableView or UITableView ). These objects are designed to fulfill a
>   specific role in a generic fashion; a window object in the AppKit
>   framework, for example, responds to mouse manipulations of its
>   controls and handles such things as closing, resizing, and moving the
>   physical window. This restricted and generic behavior necessarily
>   limits what the object can know about how an event affects (or will
>   affect) something elsewhere in the application, especially when the
>   affected behavior is specific to your application. Delegation provides
>   a way for your custom object to communicate application-specific
>   behavior to the off-the-shelf object.
>
> The programming mechanism of delegation gives objects a chance to
>   coordinate their appearance and state with changes occurring elsewhere
>   in a program, changes usually brought about by user actions. More
>   importantly, delegation makes it possible for one object to alter the
>   behavior of another object without the need to inherit from it. The
>   delegate is almost always one of your custom objects, and by
>   definition it incorporates application-specific logic that the generic
>   and delegating object cannot possibly know itself.
>
> **Data Sources**
>
> A data source is like a delegate except that, instead of being
>   delegated control of the user interface, it is delegated control of
>   data. A data source is an outlet held by NSView and UIView objects
>   such as table views and outline views that require a source from which
>   to populate their rows of visible data. The data source for a view is
>   usually the same object that acts as its delegate, but it can be any
>   object. As with the delegate, the data source must implement one or
>   more methods of an informal protocol to supply the view with the data
>   it needs and, in more advanced implementations, to handle data that
>   users directly edit in such views.
>
> As with delegates, data sources are objects that must be present to
>   receive messages from the objects requesting data. The application
>   that uses them must ensure their persistence, retaining them if
>   necessary in memory-managed code.
>
> Data sources are responsible for the persistence of the objects they
>   hand out to user-interface objects. In other words, they are
>   responsible for the memory management of those objects. However,
>   whenever a view object such as an outline view or table view accesses
>   the data from a data source, it retains the objects as long as it uses
>   the data. But it does not use the data for very long. Typically it
>   holds on to the data only long enough to display it.