# What exactly does datasource & delegate to self do?

Tags: ios7, xcode5, uiapplicationdelegate, uitableview

I often see that on the storyboard I have to setup datasource and delegate outlets to my self view controller. It surely makes stuff work, I can guess why but it would be better if this matter is cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that is why Apple writes documentation...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html

But for a more 'human' answer you can check this answer as well:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2232823/1843269