# what is the difference between delegate and datasource methods in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, datasource

I'm so confused understanding this. I don't know where to call `UIObject.delegate = self` and `UIObject.datasource = self`.

Comment: Certainly not such a noob that you couldn't look up [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/) for that?

Comment: Oh that you are (since you agree), should abandon it probably???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232147/whats-the-difference-between-data-source-and-delegate