# Custom view from NSWindowController Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, custom-view, nswindowcontroller

I have an application with two windows, the main window opens the second window that is a `NSWindowController` and in its `xib` file there is a `custom view`, is there any way to draw in this `custom view` from `NSWindowController`?

thanks

Comment: "custom view from NSWindowController"  What you are saying is illogical.

Comment: @ElTomato I have to access to nsview methods by NSWindowcrontroller, that is all I need, but the NSview is already init, so I can't use NSview *view = [[NSView alloc] init]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, I have declared two `IBOutlets`, one on `NSView`:

```
IBOutlet MyNSWindowController *wc;
```

and one on `NSWindowController`:

```
IBOutlet MyNSView *view;
```

then, I have to connected them to `custom view`.

Now I can to use its methods simply calling its `IBOutlets`.

Comment: Note that it is not a good idea to create an outlet from one window `A` to another window `B`'s view in principle -- they are supposed to exist, move, and be released independently, and they will. So the foreign outlet to `B`'s view can become nil any time for reasons outside window `A`' s control. Be careful; and consider creating a different kind of cross-connection between both windows, perhaps using a delegate that knows both window controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Override `- (void) drawRect:(NSRect) dirtyRect` in your custom NSView to do the drawing.

If you need to inform this drawRect method from your (custom) NSWindowController, you can use delegate or data source patterns by setting an outlet from the view to the NSWindowController.

Comment: Not an example but this question discusses the two approaches- https://stackoverflow.com/q/2232147/3342547